# ChromeDriver console application hide (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Can anybody help me with Python code.

When I run my .exe and open sites `chromedrive`. Run CMD how I can hide it?

What I tried already.

```
   def open_sites(urls, check_http=True, check_unreachable=True):
            options = Options()
            options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
            options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])
            options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
            options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
            options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
            service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW

            driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
```

But still CMD window appearance how I can hide it?

[CMD WINDOW CHROMEDRIVER.EXE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6IoU.png)

Comment: You mean headless mode? `options.headless=True`

Comment: No, options.headless=True dosnt open Browser. I mean when i open sites with selenium chromedriver it show me CMD window (black window) like you run chromedrive.exe

Comment: Added screenshot to my post.